# Perlin function in Unity produces small range of the same numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, perlin-noise

I am using Unity's Mathf.PerlinNoise() function to produce my perlin noise. The output of the function is always between the value 0.45f and 0.55f even though the perlin function is supposed to output values from 0 to 1.

You may think it is because I am inputting similar values but that is not the case. I have changed the input like shifting the scale, changing the offset and of course having a different x and y but they all seem to produce the same-ish values.

```
public static float terrainNoise(int x, int y, int seed, float scale, int offset)
    {
        System.Random prng = new System.Random(seed);
        float seedOffsetX = prng.Next(-100000, 100000);
        float seedOffsetY = prng.Next(-100000, 100000);

        float sampleX = ((x / LookUpData.chunkWidth) * scale) + 0.01f;
        float sampleY = ((y / LookUpData.chunkHeight) * scale) + 0.01f;

        float value = Mathf.PerlinNoise(sampleX + offset + seedOffsetX, sampleY + offset + seedOffsetY);
        Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, 1);
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: 'The noise does not contain a completely random value at each point but rather consists of "waves" whose values gradually increase and decrease across the pattern.' Seems like its working.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I see:

- Make sure chunkWidth and chunkHeight are floats, or you do `* (scale / LookupData.chunkWidth)`. That's what I see that might be causing your error. It's only sampling from a few locations because it's being snapped to grid by integer division.
- Eventually, I would forgo Unity Mathf.PerlinNoise. Not only is it not seedable, it is also Perlin noise and not a newer, less visibly grid aligned function. [Perlin above, two Simplex below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgCk.jpg). OpenSimplex2 is what I created/use/recommend, but it's certainly not the only option out there. Note that the range is -1 to 1 rather than 0 to 1, so you might need to do `value = value * 0.5f + 0.5f` if directly substituting it.